# Logger in HashMap

Tags: java, logging

I'm using java logger class to log some stuff and depending on certain data I need to configure the log to certain routes.

Let say I have the following code:

```
public class LoggerLocator {
  private static HashMap<String, Logger> loggerMap = new HashMap<String, Logger>();
  private static int count = 0;

  public Logger getLogger(String id) {
    if(!LoggerLocator.loggerMap.containsKey(id)) {
      configure(id);
    }
    return LoggerLocator.loggerMap.get(id);
  }

  private void configure(String id) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggerLocator.class.getName());
    FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(String.format("/home/abc/logs/mylog_%d.log", id), true);
    fileHandler.setFormatter(new MyFormatter());
    logger.addHandler(fh);
  }

  LoggerLocator.count++;
  LoggerLocator.loggerMap.put(id, logger);
}
```

My problem is when I do some extress test sending a lot of requests to the server, I printed the count variable in every request, which is expected to have the value of 1 but instead of that is getting the value of 2 and 2 files with the name mylog_{id}.log, mylog_{id}.log.1

Is posibble that loggerMap is empty before create the first Logger and assigning to the HashMap and another thread is getting false in  LoggerLocator.loggerMap.containsKey(id)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's not only possible that `loggerMap` is empty before you create your first logger, it most definitely is empty.  You define the variable as an empty map.  If you'd like to restrict access to the map to a single thread at a time you will most likely need to use the `syncrhonized` keyword somewhere.  Additionally I do not recommend putting `LoggerLocator.count++;` or `LoggerLocator.loggerMap.put(id, logger);` outside of any methods.  That strikes me as an anti-pattern.  Your methods `getLogger` and `configure` should also probably be static and your class definition should be `abstract` to avoid being able to/having to instantiate an instance of LoggerLocator.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are basically doing lazy initialization, you want the double check idiom:

```
if (!map.containsKey(id)){
    synchronized(map){
        if (!map.containsKey(id)){
           initialize()
        }
    }
}
```

Taking a lock after the first check ensures that regular access is fast as the lock is not taken. Doing the second check ensures that noone else has initialized the lock while you were waiting for the lock. This way you get exactly one initialization.